# gmp could not find a working compiler,

Tags: gmp

I've been struggling for the last couple of days trying to install GMP on Windows and it is not working at all. This is what I get when I run:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=${gmp_build} --build= --enable-cxx --with-gnu-ld
```

> checking build system type... sandybridge-unknown-cygwin checking host
>   system type... sandybridge-unknown-cygwin checking for a
>   BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c checking whether build
>   environment is sane... yes checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p...
>   /usr/bin/mkdir -p checking for gawk... gawk checking whether make sets
>   $(MAKE)... yes checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
>   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of
>   Makefiles... no checking ABI=64 checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic
>   -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 ... no, function pointer return checking whether cc is gcc... yes checking compiler cc -O2 -pedantic
>   -fomit-frame-pointer -m64 ... no checking ABI=x32 checking compiler gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer -mx32 ... no checking whether
>   cc is gcc... yes checking compiler cc -O2 -pedantic
>   -fomit-frame-pointer -mx32 ... no checking ABI=32 checking compiler gcc -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no checking compiler
>   gcc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no checking compiler icc
>   -no-gcc ... no checking whether cc is gcc... yes checking compiler cc -m32 -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no checking compiler cc -O2 -pedantic -fomit-frame-pointer ... no configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

Could anyone give me hand with this.

Comment: "see config.log for details"

Comment: what does config.log say? could be an issue with 64bit builds